# Kubernetes port-forwarding process silently stops or crashes when benchmarking a redis pod

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubectl, portforwarding, redis-benchmark

I have a redis pod deployed in my k8s cluster, I am running redis-benchmark to perform some benchmarking. To do this, I port-forward the pod to be able to send requests from outside the cluster. I am firing the following redis benchmark command:

```
redis-benchmark -h localhost -c 8000 -n 2000000
```

The problem happens when I set the number of clients -c to 4000 or more the port-forwarding process silently crashes or stops. However, the same command works well when I execute the command from within the container.

So my question is, is there a limit to how many requests a port-forwarded container could handle?

Note: I have done the following:

1. Increase redis max client from 10,000 to 60K
2. Increase open files limits on the source machine to 65K

So I am lost as to how this would work when executed inside a container but would fail when the execution is done through port forwarding.

Comment: Did - by any chance - the redis port restart?

Comment: Can you be specific please, what do you mean by port restart? If you mean pod restart, not the pod stays alive. But I have to restart the port forwarding to be able to connect again.

Comment: Sorry, typo; "port" should be "pod".

Comment: no the pod stays alive as specified in my my comment above